On window, creating beamer document in vscode does not work
I am using Window11, and VSCode for latex.
When I build the .tex file, I encounter this problem, and dont know why.
When I use article class, no problem happen, but when I use beamer class, problem happen
My latex code is very simple.
\documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{test}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

and the error log is too long, in the last part, it says
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemedefault.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerfontthemedefault.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemedefault.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamericonbook.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I dont know what this error means, if someone can help me, I will really appreciate!
thanks in advance.
EDIT
I added full text error log.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.13)  21 NOV 2024 13:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**c:/Users/seungdae.han/Desktop/HSD/documents/sampling/presentation/first/firstpresentation
(c:/Users/seungdae.han/Desktop/HSD/documents/sampling/presentation/first/firstpresentation.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2024/01/06 v3.71 A class for typesetting presentations
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count188
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box51
\beamer@tempcount=\count189
\c@beamerpauses=\count190
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count191
\beamer@minimum=\count192
\beamer@decode@box=\box52
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box53
\beamer@modecount=\count193
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
\headdp=\dimen140
\footheight=\dimen141
\sidebarheight=\dimen142
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen143
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen144
\beamer@animht=\dimen145
\beamer@animdp=\dimen146
\beamer@animwd=\dimen147
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen148
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen149
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen150
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen151
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen152
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen153
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen154
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen155
\beamer@lastskip=\skip48
\beamer@areabox=\box54
\beamer@animcurrent=\box55
\beamer@animshowbox=\box56
\beamer@sectionbox=\box57
\beamer@logobox=\box58
\beamer@linebox=\box59
\beamer@sectioncount=\count194
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count195
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count196
\beamer@sectionmax=\count197
\beamer@totalheads=\count198
\beamer@headcounter=\count199
\beamer@partstartpage=\count266
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count267
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count268
\beamer@animationtempa=\count269
\beamer@animationtempb=\count270
\beamer@xpos=\count271
\beamer@ypos=\count272
\beamer@ypos@offset=\count273
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count274
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count275
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count276
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count277
\beamer@toclastsection=\count278
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count279
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip49
\beamer@paperheight=\skip50
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count280
\Gm@cntv=\count281
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count282
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen157
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen158
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen159
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen160
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen161
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen162
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen163
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen164
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen165
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box60
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks20
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks21
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks22
))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen166
\pgf@xa=\dimen167
\pgf@xb=\dimen168
\pgf@xc=\dimen169
\pgf@y=\dimen170
\pgf@ya=\dimen171
\pgf@yb=\dimen172
\pgf@yc=\dimen173
\c@pgf@counta=\count283
\c@pgf@countb=\count284
\c@pgf@countc=\count285
\c@pgf@countd=\count286
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen174
\pgfmath@count=\count287
\pgfmath@box=\box61
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count288
))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen175
\Gin@req@width=\dimen176
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@x=\dimen177
\pgf@y=\dimen178
\pgf@xa=\dimen179
\pgf@ya=\dimen180
\pgf@xb=\dimen181
\pgf@yb=\dimen182
\pgf@xc=\dimen183
\pgf@yc=\dimen184
\pgf@xd=\dimen185
\pgf@yd=\dimen186
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count289
\c@pgf@countb=\count290
\c@pgf@countc=\count291
\c@pgf@countd=\count292
\t@pgf@toka=\toks26
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks27
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks28
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count293
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count294
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count295
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen187
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen188
\pgf@picminy=\dimen189
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen190
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen191
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen192
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen193
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen194
\pgf@xx=\dimen195
\pgf@xy=\dimen196
\pgf@yx=\dimen197
\pgf@yy=\dimen198
\pgf@zx=\dimen199
\pgf@zy=\dimen256
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen257
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen258
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen259
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen260
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box62
\pgf@hbox=\box63
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box64
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count296
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen261
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen262
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen263
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen264
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen265
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen266
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count297
\pgf@shadingcount=\count298
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box65
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count299
\XC@countmixins=\count300
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count301
)
\@linkdim=\dimen267
\Hy@linkcounter=\count302
\Hy@pagecounter=\count303
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count304
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Option `implicit' set `false' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode OFF; no redefinition of LaTeX internals.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count305
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen268
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count306
\Field@Width=\dimen269
\Fld@charsize=\dimen270
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.
\Hy@abspage=\count307


Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count308
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count309
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks29
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
Package: sansmathaccent 2020/01/31
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script package (logo)
))))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty
Package: translator 2021-05-31 v1.12d Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty
\beamer@argscount=\count310
\beamer@lastskipcover=\skip51
\beamer@trivlistdepth=\count311
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty
\c@lecture=\count312
\c@part=\count313
\c@section=\count314
\c@subsection=\count315
\c@subsubsection=\count316
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty
\beamer@framebox=\box66
\beamer@frametitlebox=\box67
\beamer@zoombox=\box68
\beamer@zoomcount=\count317
\beamer@zoomframecount=\count318
\beamer@frametextheight=\dimen271
\c@subsectionslide=\count319
\beamer@frametopskip=\skip52
\beamer@framebottomskip=\skip53
\beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\skip54
\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\skip55
\beamer@envbody=\toks30
\framewidth=\dimen272
\c@framenumber=\count320
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty
\beamer@splitbox=\box69
\beamer@autobreakcount=\count321
\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\dimen273
\beamer@frametitletoks=\toks31
\beamer@framesubtitletoks=\toks32
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty
\beamer@footins=\box70
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty
\beamer@frameboxcopy=\box71
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks33
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty
\bmb@box=\box72
\bmb@colorbox=\box73
\bmb@boxwidth=\dimen274
\bmb@boxheight=\dimen275
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen276
\bmb@temp=\dimen277
\bmb@dima=\dimen278
\bmb@dimb=\dimen279
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen280
)
\beamer@blockheadheight=\dimen281
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2023/07/04 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks34
)
\beamer@bibiconwidth=\skip56
\c@figure=\count322
\c@table=\count323
\abovecaptionskip=\skip57
\belowcaptionskip=\skip58
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigationsymbols.tex)
\beamer@section@min@dim=\dimen282
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip59

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks35
\ex@=\dimen283
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen284
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count324
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count325
\leftroot@=\count326
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count327
\DOTSCASE@=\count328
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box74
\strutbox@=\box75
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen285
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count329
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count330
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count331
\dspbrk@lvl=\count332
\tag@help=\toks36
\row@=\count333
\column@=\count334
\maxfields@=\count335
\andhelp@=\toks37
\eqnshift@=\dimen286
\alignsep@=\dimen287
\tagshift@=\dimen288
\tagwidth@=\dimen289
\totwidth@=\dimen290
\lineht@=\dimen291
\@envbody=\toks38
\multlinegap=\skip60
\multlinetaggap=\skip61
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks39
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks40
\thm@bodyfont=\toks41
\thm@headfont=\toks42
\thm@notefont=\toks43
\thm@headpunct=\toks44
\thm@preskip=\skip62
\thm@postskip=\skip63
\thm@headsep=\skip64
\dth@everypar=\toks45
)
\c@theorem=\count336
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemedefault.sty (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerfontthemedefault.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemedefault.sty) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamericonbook.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz commented, I tried
tlmgr update -self -all

and it says
C:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
C:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
C:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

And when I use lualatex mytexfile.tex on my command-line, it also raised error and log is
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.11.13)  22 NOV 2024 08:53
 restricted system commands enabled.
**.\firstpresentation.tex
(./firstpresentation.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/luatex-ca
che/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-
28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/luatex-ca
che/generic/names".
( Some logs ... ) 

! error:  (file beamericonbook.pdf) (pdf inclusion): reading image failed
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


welcome! what does kpsewhich beamericonbook.pdf return?

@cfr thanks!
the result of 'kpsewhich beamericonbook.pdf' is:  c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamericonbook.pdf

please add the full log to your question.

@cfr thanks! I added full log to my question!

Compiles just fine for me on Linux. Is the TL24 up to date?

@user14096975 Could you run tlmgr update -self -all? This would make it easier to compare .log files.

Does it work if you compile from the command line? Does it work if you compile with e.g. lualatex?

@daleif thanks! how can I make TL24 up to date? is TL24 TexLive 2024?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks! I tried 'tlmgr update -self -all' and it raise some errors.
Also, I tried to compile from the command line. But It also raise similar error, I appended the log above.

Please cite those errors

@daleif thanks, I appended all errors at the end of my question.

@user14096975 it looks like there is something fishy with your texlive installation. Maybe make a separate question about the problems with the update. Maybe the other problems will solve themselves once your installation is repaired.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, maybe there could be some problems with textlive installation.. I will check it.
